# How to 'implement' functions from inner object onto the outer struct?

Tags: rust

given this example

```rust
struct Outer<T>(*mut T);

impl<T> Outer<T> {
    pub fn new(value: &mut T) -> Outer<T> {
        Outer(value as *mut T)
    }
}

struct Inner(pub i32);
impl Inner {
    pub fn do_thing(&self) {
        println!("did the thing {}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let outer = Outer::new(Inner(2));
    outer.do_thing() // error: do_thing doesnt exist
}
```

how would i expose the methods of `Inner` as methods of `Outer`

im trying to achieve what `Box` is doing

Comment: [`delegate`](https://docs.rs/delegate/latest/delegate/) (I would have expected this to be a duplicate, but can't find anything.)

Comment: @Caesar ive just tried that. the problem is delegate cant figure out the functions since the inner type of `Outer` is generic.

Comment: If `Outer` is a transparent wrapper then you can implement `Deref` for `Outer` with `Deref::Target = T`. In general, this is appropriate for smart pointers, but not a good general mechanism for simulating inheritance.

Comment: @PeterHall sorry i shouldve specified this. but T can sometimes be a trait object so that wouldnt work since `Outer` isnt sized

Comment: The target type doesn't need to be sized to use `Deref`.

Comment: deref is implemented but everytime i try to use either `*` or `.deref()`, compiler says that i either cant use it or it doesnt exist

Comment: @Cezarhg2007 Yes, you shouldn't call those directly. Auto-deref rules mean you can just call the method on the outer and it will automatically delegate to the result of calling `deref()`.

Comment: @PeterHall you forgot to generate the link

Comment: sorry everyone, im gonna edit the question since maybe its something to do with the pointers im using

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e6801017b378b91908696fdd6e34a01

Comment: ive figured out why everything isnt working. since `Inner` is a global. the generic is (dyn T + 'static), this is why i cant call methods of T. is it possible to remove 'static someway but still keeping things global

Comment: Can you update your post with what you've tried? Its not clear to me that `'static` would have any affect on `Deref` or method calls. Do you have a *pointer* to a trait object or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reborrow the pointer in order to implement `Deref` [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd4dd5c48c49f3a760b3f13925147e92):

```rs
impl<T: ?Sized> Deref for Outer<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { &*self.0 }
    }
}
```

Answer from before the edit below:

---

The clean way is to have methods that return the inner type:

```rs
impl<T> Outer<T> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.0
    }
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.0
    }
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}
```

This is more useful when the inner type isn't `pub` (you can just do `self.0` for the same effect as all three methods), but is a common pattern that users of rust libraries expect.

The other way is to implement [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html). This is messier because it's a very strong API commitment: you now have all the methods of the inner type added to the outer type unconditionally, and gain any future methods. It also means that any namespace collisions between the wrapper and the target are hard to notice, which is why things like `Arc::get_mut` are associated functions instead of methods. If you use this, consider changing methods on the wrapper to associated functions (don't take a `self` parameter).

```rs
impl<T> Deref for Outer<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried the exact same thing as you did above. yet error. either function `.do_thing()` cant be found or when i implicitly try to call deref, it says deref doesnt exist or cant be called on the `Outer`

Comment: jesus christ. problem has been fixed. i left out the little `: ?Sized` on the deref implementation by accident, added it and everything works. thank you for the help

Comment: @Cezarhg2007 Note this is unsound: it can be used to cause use-after-free (no lifetimes).